# Android GridView Items Shuffles Repeates

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

Following is the adapter

```
public class AdapterCases extends BaseAdapter{
List<Case> lstCases;
Context mContext;
ViewHolder holder;
LawyersInfo user_info;
public AdapterCases(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<Case> cases, LawyersInfo user_info) {
    lstCases = cases;
    mContext = context;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    this.user_info = user_info;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid_cli_law, parent,false);
        holder.tvPName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        holder.tvCName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);
        holder.tvCaNo=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCaseNo);
        holder.tvCaType=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCaseType);
        holder.tvCaDate=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCaseDate);
        holder.btnViewDetail=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewDetail);
        holder.ivPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        holder.llRow = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llRow);
        holder.tvPName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ivPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvCaNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvCaType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvCaDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnViewDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final Case p=lstCases.get(position);
    /*String name= "";
    if((null!=p.first_name)&&(!p.first_name.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))){
        name=p.first_name;
    }
    if((null!=p.last_name)&&(p.last_name.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))){
        name = name+ " "+p.last_name;
    }*/
    holder.tvCaNo.setText(p.case_ref_number);
    holder.tvCaType.setText(p.case_title);
    holder.tvCaDate.setText(p.case_status);
    holder.tvCName.setText(p.case_cost);
    holder.btnViewDetail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, CaseDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("case", p);
            i.putExtra("info", user_info);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    holder.llRow.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .setTitle(p.case_title)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the case permanantly?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            lstCases.remove(position);
                        //  Toast.makeText(mContext, lstCases.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                            //lstCases.remove(position);
                            //notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    public LinearLayout llRow;
    public ImageView ivPic;
    public Button btnViewDetail;
    public TextView tvCaDate;
    public TextView tvCaType;
    public TextView tvCaNo;
    public TextView tvCName;
    public TextView tvPName;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return lstCases.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lstCases.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return lstCases.get(position).hashCode();
}
```

}

Following is my gridView

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvClientsLawyers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="3">
</GridView>
```

Problem is that as i scroll down to see more items the items in the first row can be seen in the last row also sometimes in the same order and sometimes shuffled. And as I scroll i can see an item's text change as i scroll down and then again change when i scroll up. I applied holder pattern too. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want your `ViewHolder` to be a global variable.  Remove that and it's instantiation from the constructor.  Instead you only ever want it to be a local variable to the `getView` method.  Eg:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //Continue with handling view creation
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Hey thank you very much that tip actually solved my problem. It was like that because I was making the viewholder global.